# Angle Function occasionally returns NaN

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, nan, angle

I have this angle function I'm using for a Unity project, but it occasionally returns NaN, and I don't understand why. I copied this code from the internet, so I don't fully understand how it works

```
    public static float Angle(Vector3 vec1, Vector3 angleVec, Vector3 vec2)
    {
        float lengthA = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(angleVec.x - vec1.x, 2) + Mathf.Pow(angleVec.y - vec1.y, 2));
        float lengthB = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(vec2.x - angleVec.x, 2) + Mathf.Pow(vec2.y - angleVec.y, 2));
        float lengthC = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(vec2.x - vec1.x, 2) + Mathf.Pow(vec2.y - vec1.y, 2));

        float calc = ((lengthA * lengthA) + (lengthB * lengthB) - (lengthC * lengthC)) / (2 * lengthA * lengthB);
        float returnAngle = Mathf.Acos(calc) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        if (System.Single.IsNaN(returnAngle))
        {
            Debug.LogError("NAN");
        }
        return returnAngle;

    }
```

Can someone help me fix this code

Comment: Arc cosine is undefined for certain values.  See [here](https://socratic.org/questions/why-is-cos-arccos-3-have-an-answer-of-undefined-but-arccos-cos-2-is-outside-the-#:~:text=The%20cosine%20function%20has%20a,of%20the%20domain%20for%20arccos%20.).

Comment: @PranavHosangadi: Yes, which is explained in the article I linked.

Answer (score 2):

The cosine function has a range of [-1, 1], so the arccosine function has a domain of [-1, 1]. This means for any x outside [-1, 1], arccos(x) is undefined.

If `lengthA` or `lengthB` is 0, `calc` is infinity and `acos(infinity)` is undefined.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/S3zwr5

You will have to write an `if` statement handling this case.

Comment: I added some debug code, and the function returned NaN even when all 3 length variables where non-zero. I tested it, and when lengthA=1.4, lengthB=98, and lengthC=98.4, it still returns NaN

Comment: @Gumbus, I'm not sure if something's wrong with Unity's `Mathf`, but https://dotnetfiddle.net/3emghh using .NET's MathF works fine...